# How to include an Ionic Directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I would like to use http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavButtons/ as a way of adjusting what's shown in the header/nav bar based on the route where the elements shown in the header are set in the view.

```
 <!-- The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate -->
<ion-nav-bar>
</ion-nav-bar>

<!-- where the initial view template will be rendered -->
<ion-nav-view>
  <ion-view>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
      <button class="button" ng-click="doSomething()">
        I'm a button on the left of the navbar!
      </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content>
      Some super content here!
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</ion-nav-view>
```

However when I try to use that code, the directive is undefined. It must separate from the ionic.js, which I'm including in the page. Is there a special way to add it as a directive or just copy the code from github (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/driftyco/ionic/master/js/angular/directive/navBar.js)? When I just include the directive, I get `IonicModule is undefined` in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Well you'll need your main app module depending on the `'ionic'` module. (i.e. in your index.html somewhere you have `ng-app="myApp"` - and then in a script somewhere you have `angular.module('myApp', [/* dependencies */]);` - you need to add `'ionic'` to the dependencies.)  Have you done this?

Also I'd just find a minified/complete version of the ionic files for javascript and angular; however if you just wanted that single directive, you minimally will need this, too, as that is where the `IonicModule` is defined.  It looks like from your error message you haven't done this.

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/js/angular/main.js

If you can set up a plunker that will help (me help) even more.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I have added 'ionic' to the dependencies. I'll try adding main.js, but where is the complete ionic framework? It would be awesome if I can just install that via bower, much cleaner.

Comment: @Steve: It doesn't look like they have (and I may be wrong about this) bower for their angular files, but I think all the files in question should be here: http://code.ionicframework.com/#